# Sideload failing for web outlook add-in per official guide

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, yeoman-generator

Been developing a small add-in that was working fine... now I can't seem to get any local add-in project sideloaded from localhost as the MS guide describes! (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator)

Tried npm start(instead of npm run dev-server), output as follows:

```
The dev server is running on port 3000. Process id: 16396
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Error: Unable to start debugging.
office-addin-debugging: Unable to sideload the Office Add-in.
Error: Sideload is not supported.
```

The projects used to show up in the ellipsis menu on web outlook, now they won't load at all.

Tried creating a brand new project, no luck.

checked this very similar thread, no luck. [Unable to sideload the Office Add-in when running 'npm start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743701/unable-to-sideload-the-office-add-in-when-running-npm-start)

...oof

Comment: From the document you linked, did you try this part: "Follow the instructions in Sideload Outlook add-ins for testing to sideload the add-in in Outlook.", which links you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing ? If so, did you get any error trying to sideload?

Comment: Yes, that was my normal method of sideloading. My app compiles in npm just fine, seems to be accepted by the 'add custom add-in' menu, but does not appear in the ellipsis menu. Script Lab does appear there, installed through appsource but no custom add-ins...

Comment: Sorry this, should have been asked first, but what client are you using to test this? OWA, Mac, Windows? etc.

Comment: No problem, still having the issue. I am using the web version of outlook to test/sideload, on chrome win10.

Comment: Following up with some people, sideloading from npm run dev-server isn't supported. (it will be coming soon). And you have to install the app manually via the link we provided earlier. After you do this, does it show up in your installed add-ins (under Manage Add-ins?). If it IS there, then there may be some issue inside your manifest, that is preventing it from showing up. If it ISN'T there...it should have given you an error when you tried manually sideload.

Comment: That seems odd to me- I was following this tutorial(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial) which suggests npm run dev-server, then manually adding via "add custom add-in" and this was working fine! Did something change? I'm not sure how the manifest could be causing problems if its a fresh yeoman generated add-in...

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused you. It IS supported, to create the manifest via yeoman, and then manually add via add custom add-ins. But the support of doing it all from NPM is coming in the future (I guess that was more trivia than useful information)

Comment: I am also not sure, how something could go wrong. This should be working...If other add-ins are loading. That is why I suggested to make sure the add-in got installed. The other thing to do, is to make sure you switch emails AFTER you install the add-in. Or perhaps check on other platforms (like Win32 / Mac). If you can provide the manifest, maybe we can see if there is something missing that is necessary. (or maybe there is a bug in OWA code..)

Comment: Here is the link to the manifest for the add-in I was working on: https://gist.github.com/gonsalvg/d8c59a8749416c19334a336b03ee5823 Going back to your previous comment I did not encounter any errors manually sideloading, and each add-in I sideload has the blue checkmark indicating it installed ok though it does not appear with the rest of the add-ins.

Comment: Installed your manifest, and posted pictures in the below answer, to show you what results I was seeing. I wanted to make sure you were seeing close to the same thing, and if maybe you can show screenshots of what you are seeing incorrectly. Perhaps try your manifest on an Outlook.com account? (are you on an on-prem exchange server?)

Answer (score 0):

Installing your test Manifest I see the following:

In the Add-ins button:

[image]

In The ellipsis I see:

[image]

So it's working for me in OWA, and I also saw similar results in Win32 Desktop Outlook. Are you on a private exchange server? Does your manifest work on an Outlook.com account?

Comment: Wow that's so strange, so it must be on my end somehow... In any case, I deeply appreciate your assistance! I am not on any private exchange server, and I'm not sure what you mean by outlook.com account. I was using my normal msft account (@live.com) where it was working fine. I did try to load the manifest on Firefox which had the same issue where it says it is added but does not appear in the ellipsis.

Comment: outlook.com means Outlook.live.com .I have tried to install the shared manifest on Chrome and Firefox browser and i was able to successfully install it on both the browsers and on both kind of outlook account(Outlook.live.com and outlook.office.com).The steps which i followed to download it are:-
1)Downloaded the Zip file from the manifest link which you shared
2)Open Add store and Click on My Add-in 
3)Click on Add a custom Addin 
I hope it helps

Comment: No, that's not helpful unfortunately. Alright, well after many hours of trying to figure this out I am just going to move to another machine so I can continue working. If I can find the appropriate github repo I will file an issue with all of my info so that hopefully nobody else runs into this bug. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of error which you are getting when trying to install the add-in?