# Which framework to use for developing Microsoft Office 365 add-in

Tags: linux, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

- I am thinking to develop a Microsoft Office 365 Excel Add-in. I am working with `Linux` as my Operating System.
- I came across `Visual Studio IDE` and `Yeoman Generator`, but `Visual Studio IDE` doesn't work with Linux, and `Yeoman Generator` works but when I do `npm start` I get a error saying

```
Error: Unable to start debugging.
Error: Unable to sideload the Office Add-in.
Error: Platform not support Linux.
```

- Do I need to use `Windows` or `MAC` only for the development of `Microsoft Office Add-in`?
- Or can I make use of any other framework like `electron` but I am not able to find much of a documentation on other frameworks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to sideload the Office Add-in when running 'npm start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743701/unable-to-sideload-the-office-add-in-when-running-npm-start)

Comment: it doesn't, for me it is showing additionally that ```Platform not supported``` as I am using Linux. The link you shared is around ```windows``` and ```mac```.

Comment: I've never seen docs for debugging office add-ins on Linux. Have you ever seen MS Office for Linux?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No, I haven't. There is a way around to install ```MS Office``` on ```Linux``` using ```Play on Linux```.

Comment: Have you tried to sideload the add-in manually and then try to debug it on Linux? Have you tried to just run a local web server instead of `npm start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `npm start` is trying to open desktop Office and sideload the add-in. But you get that error because there is no desktop Office for Linux. You have to sideload and debug in Office on the web if you want to develop on a Linux computer.

Also, if you used yeoman generator, there should be a script named start:web in the package.json file. So you can try automatically sideload on the web like this:

Run the following command in the root directory of your project. When you run this command, the local web server starts. Replace "{url}" with the URL of an Excel document on your OneDrive or a SharePoint library to which you have permissions.

```
npm run start:web -- --document {url}
```

The following are examples.

```
npm run start:web -- --document https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/EZGxP7ksiE5DuxvY638G798BpuhwluxCMfF1WZQj3VYhYQ?e=F4QM1R
npm run start:web -- --document https://1drv.ms/x/s!jkcH7spkM4EGgcZUgqthk4IK3NOypVw?e=Z6G1qp
npm run start:web -- --document https://contoso-my.sharepoint-df.com/:t:/p/user/EQda453DNTpFnl1bFPhOVR0BwlrzetbXvnaRYii2lDr_oQ?e=RSccmNP
```

Also, take a look at [Debug add-ins on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview#debug-on-linux).

Comment: That question is a good indicator to add some bits about Linux to the Office Dev docs.

Comment: We have the bits that I linked to in the last sentence of my answer. There's really not a whole lot more that could be said about developing on Linux. This is what we call a "discoverability" problem. The documentation is there, but this user didn't find it.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the link posted, but this bit of information doesn't reflect all the considerations for the linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

Because add-ins are developed using HTML and JavaScript, they are designed to work across platforms, but there might be subtle differences in how different browsers render the HTML.

On the Mac OS (but not on Linux) you can use `VSCode` with yeoman generator to create a skeleton of the Office add-in. Also you may debug add-ins on the Mac OS, see [Debug Office Add-ins on a Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac) for more information.

All platforms where MS Office for desktop is used/deployed are supported - Mac OS and Windows. But I've never heard about MS Office on Linux.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: MacOS is not only "not a pure Linux", it's "not a linux at all". Maybe you're confusing with the fact that it's UNIX.

Comment: Yes, I've corrected my post. Thank you.